# Cython and PyCharm - error that does not occur in Python from Terminal

Tags: python, pycharm, cython

I have a very weird error during import of a compiled cython function. I say weird because everything works just fine if I use python from Terminal instead of Pycharm console. Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
 File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
 module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/Users/(me)/Analysis/analysis.py", line 8, in <module>
 from cfunctions import Cpotts_energy
 File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
 module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/(me)/Analysis/cfunctions.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyCapsule_New
 Referenced from: /Users/(me)/Analysis/cfunctions.so
 Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/(me)/Analysis/cfunctions.so
```

The C function is just an easy array sum, but as I said no errors occur using python from Terminal, so I guess PyCharm itself might be involved in some obscure setup that exceeds from my newbie knowledge.

Mac OS 10.11.1, Python 2.7.3

Any clues?

Comment: You are using a custom Python interpreter in your shell, which is not configured correctly in PyCharm (pycharm doesn't know about your dotfiles, ie, it does not know about `~/.bash_profile`). So you need to set the interpreter correctly from settings for your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the file compiles properly from the terminal, in Pycharm go to:

> Run > Edit Configurations > Python Interpreter

and make sure that you are using the same Python version when running from the terminal and in Pycharm. Also install all the necessary Python headers and libraries you might need.

Other Python installations (such as Canopy or Anaconda) can interfere with the system's Python. If you have one of those distributions and you don't use it, you should remove it completely to avoid problems. Check the distribution's official documentation for the uninstall instructions.

Comment: OK, I think something is happening related to a previously-installed IDE (Enthought Canopy) which might have a own version of python which is now running by default from my terminal. If I run `type -a python` it gives me `python is /Users/lorenzo/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python
python is /usr/bin/python`. Do you think I can/should merge the version used by PyCharm with the one used by Canopy?